# How to recognize user login when log in comes from cookie?

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, authentication

In our project we give the users points for every day they visit the site.

The issue is that the user doesn't always log in in an explicit way (e.g. submitting login form), but often when he comes back he's logged in thanks to the cookie session id set by Django and we can't recognize his login in any way.

How can I check if the user has logged in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this in middleware. Have an attribute in the profile, or the session, which records the date the user was last seen, and in the middleware check if it is < today: if so, award the points and update the field.